# Unable to see custom facet in List Manager Campaign dashboard

Tags: exm, list-manager

I have implemented a custom facet. I see it in the list manager importer but am unable to see it on the List campaign Dashboard.

I have created a TestFacet.

```
public class TestFacet : Facet
{
    public TestFacet()
    {

    }
    public const string DefaultFacetKey = "TestFacet";
    public string TestFacetID { get; set; }
}
```

[image: CustomImporterTestFacet]
Custom facet(test facet) showing up in importer. ^

[image: Dashboard]
Unable to see the column test facet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]To get an extra column in List Manager dashboard, You need to add a column.

1. Change to **Core** database.
2. Go to /sitecore/client/Applications/List Manager/Lists/Contact list
3. Add a new item or copy an existing one.  Provide a header for the
   column.
4. Fill in your facet name in the **DataField** field.

This should work. If you face any issues then please check the facet configurations in configs and indexing of the custom facet config.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Great that worked. But the data is not imported into the column. `DataField` under `Lists/ContactList/TestFacet` is set to TestFacet and my import model under `TabControl Param/Map/ImportModel/TestFacet` DataField is set to TestFacet. Is there any other configuration I need to set?

Comment: There is no straight way to do this. To get data, apart from the indexing of the custom facet, you need to also customize the "FetchEntities" method in "Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.ContactsController" class. But this should be only done when you do not want to use segmented lists, otherwise you will run into problems. Basically, I will not recommend this.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain properly. In your example pic, 'Business segment' is empty. What steps would I have to do to ensure data importing via csv import.

Comment: Please refer to the following blogs:
https://kbdocssitecore.wordpress.com/2020/03/19/creating-custom-contact-facets-in-sitecore/

https://kbdocssitecore.wordpress.com/2020/03/19/display-custom-contact-facet-data-in-sitecore-contact-list/

I hope this helps.

Comment: How would I implement a predefined facet to map? I.e. 'Personal_Title' facet? What is its facet name? @Somnath

Comment: @LinkedListT The above post is updated with the answer to this. Please refer to the same and post your question on the comment box in the post.